# Javadoc not found. (Netbeans 8.2)

Tags: java, netbeans, javadoc

Estoy teniendo un problema con Netbeans 8.2, en el que no puedo usar ningún método de algún paquete importado en alguna clase que no sea el main de un programa. Me arroja este mensaje en esos objetos:

Javadoc not found. Either Javadoc documentation for this item does not exist or you have not added specified Javadoc in the Java Platform Manager or the Library Manager.

Clase cualquiera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Clase main:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya intenté copiar y pegar los URLs y adjuntar el ZIP de Javadocs 8, pero no ha funcionado. También desinstalé el programa, instalé Netbeans 12.3, lo volví a desinstalar y reinstalar el 8.2, pero no he tenido éxito.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Qué otra cosa puedo hacer? Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Aquí esta una misma pregunta que hicieron y ahí responden mucha suerte. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8504572/netbeans-says-javadocs-not-found